# XPath expression in filter mediator

Tags: xpath, filter, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB to process and distribute HL7.
I want to filter HL7 based on its content.
Message passing in the ESB is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<hl7:message xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7">
<ADT_A01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
    <MSH>
        <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
        <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
        <MSH.3>
            <HD.1>HL7Soup</HD.1>
        </MSH.3>
        <MSH.4>
            <HD.1>Instance1</HD.1>
        </MSH.4>
        <MSH.5>
            <HD.1>HL7Soup</HD.1>
        </MSH.5>
        <MSH.6>
            <HD.1>Instance2</HD.1>
        </MSH.6>
        <MSH.7>
            <TS.1>200808181126</TS.1>
        </MSH.7>
        <MSH.8>SECURITY</MSH.8>
        <MSH.9>
            <MSG.1>ADT</MSG.1>
            <MSG.2>A04</MSG.2>
        </MSH.9>
        <MSH.10>MSG00001</MSH.10>
        <MSH.11>
            <PT.1>P</PT.1>
        </MSH.11>
        <MSH.12>
            <VID.1>2.5.1</VID.1>
        </MSH.12>
    </MSH>
    ...................
    </ADT_A01.INSURANCE>
</ADT_A01></hl7:message></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to filter HL7 messages based on  content. If ADT OK ELSE Drop it. I tried with the following filter mediator but it's not working. It's always going to the else branch :

```
<filter regex=".*ADT.*" source="//MSG.1[1]">
    <then>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="ADT" value="Oui"/>
        </log>
    </then>
    <else>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="ADT" value="Non"/>
        </log>
    </else>
</filter>
```

The xpath expression is working in online tester like https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
What's wrong?

Comment: WSO2 ESB is definitely something very blurry to me :(

Comment: You are not paying attention to the default namespace the XML is in. `//MSG.1` will never select anything, because there are no `<MSG.1>` nodes in your XML. Your XML has `<MSG.1 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">` nodes, you have to address them as `//xyz:MSG.1` in XPath, and you have to register `xyz` as the namespace prefix for `urn:hl7-org:v2xml` in your filter.

Comment: (Of course you don't have to use `xyz` as the namespace prefix. You pick a better moniker for this namespace.)

Comment: Thanks you Tomalak! It works! I must admit that I am not used to handling XML but as the xpath expression worked in the test site..... For the next ones, my filter looks like:
<filter regex=".*ADT.*" source="//hl7:MSG.1[1]" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">

Comment: Perfect, that looks about right. I know why it failed, but I have don't have insight into WSO2 ESB, so I've not written that as an actual answer. You're invited to write up your own answer that has the necessary details in this particular context.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following proxy for your use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="filter-hl7"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="log1" value="API invoked"/>
         </log>
         <filter xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7"
                 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                 xpath="contains(name(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hl7:message/*),'ADT')">
            <then>
               <log level="full">
                  <property name="log2" value="######### Xpath matched!"/>
               </log>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="full">
                   <property name="log3" value="########## Xpath did not match!"/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

This Xpath works in the proxy.

```
contains(name(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hl7:message/*),'ADT')
```